# jquery .submit() not triggering though am using $(document).delegate()

Tags: jquery

```
 <div class="sld_dwn">
 <form class="sign_in_form" id='target'>
 <div>
 <a class="sign_in_data" >email:</a>
 </br>
 <input type="text" class="sign_in_box" name='txt1'>
 <a class="sign_in_data1">password:</a>
 </br>
 <input type="password" class="sign_in_box1"name='txt2' >
 </div>
 <a href='http://localhost' class="forgot">forgot password</a></br>
 <!--<input type="checkbox"><a class="stay">stay signin</a>-->
 <input type='submit' class="but_signin1" value='Sign in'>
 </form>
```

File containing jquery code is sginin.js and am trying access jquery library from
 http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js
    `$("document").ready(function()
     {
     $("document").delegate('#target','submit',function(e)
     {
     alert('hi');
     return false;`
     style given to the above div is
     `div.sld_dwn
     {
      position:relative;
      border-radius:0px;
      display:none;
      float:right;
      right:40px;
      background-color:#3E003E;
      background-color:RGBA(255, 255, 255,0.2);
      color:white;
      border:0px;
      width:450px;
      height:120px;
      }`

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/rbuh2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way selecting the document ready handlers, This should be like:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
//^------^--------------------------------remove the quotes and see if works
       $(document).delegate('#target','submit',function(e) { 
//  ----^-------^------------------------------------------------and this one too
          alert('hi'); 
          return false;
       });
 });
```